# Left aligning equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I am trying to left align my equations as follows:
[image]

I got the following code from other posts but I don't really understand what exactly to do.

```
\begin{flalign}
&& g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{2}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{3}(t + \Delta t)) \notag \\
&& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{2}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{3}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t) \notag\\
&& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t), x^{*}_{2}(t), x^{*}_{3}(t)) + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{1}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{2}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{3}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t
\end{flalign}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're placing the additional `&` in the wrong place.

I present two alternative ways, as `flalign` doesn't seem really right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show the margins

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
&g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{2}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{3}(t + \Delta t)) & \notag \\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{2}(t) 
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{3}(t)
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t) & \notag\\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t), x^{*}_{2}(t), x^{*}_{3}(t))
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{1}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{2}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{3}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t &
\end{flalign}

\begin{align}
&g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{2}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{3}(t + \Delta t)) \notag \\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{2}(t) 
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{3}(t)
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t) \notag\\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t), x^{*}_{2}(t), x^{*}_{3}(t))
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{1}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{2}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{3}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{2}(t + \Delta t), x^{*}_{3}(t + \Delta t)) \\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t) + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{2}(t) 
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t, x^{*}_{3}(t)
    + \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t) \\
& = g_{1}(x^{*}_{1}(t), x^{*}_{2}(t), x^{*}_{3}(t))
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{1}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{1}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{2}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{2}}{\partial t} \Delta t
  + \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x^{*}_{3}} \frac{\partial x^{*}_{3}}{\partial t} \Delta t
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last two realizations are identical, but the final one is easier to type.

Comment: +1. Just curious: Why not increase the size of the "outer" parentheses in row 2 to, say, `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`?

Comment: @Mico I didn't even try to interpret those formulas. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment. That way, you don't need all those `\notag` directives. Next. I would shift lines 2 and 3 slightly to the right. Finally, I'd increase the size of the "outer" parentheses in line 2 to `\Big`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "aligned" environment

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
& g_1\bigl(
  x^*_1(t +\Delta t),
  x^*_2(t +\Delta t),
  x^*_3(t +\Delta t)
  \bigr) \\
&\quad= g_1\Bigl(
  x^*_1(t) + \frac{\partial x^*_1}{\partial t}\Delta t,
  x^*_2(t) + \frac{\partial x^*_2}{\partial t}\Delta t,
  x^*_3(t) + \frac{\partial x^*_3}{\partial t}\Delta t
  \Bigr) \\
&\quad= g_1\bigl(x^*_1(t), x^*_2(t), x^*_3(t)\bigr)
+ \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x^*_1} \frac{\partial x^*_1}{\partial t}\Delta t
+ \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x^*_2} \frac{\partial x^*_2}{\partial t}\Delta t
+ \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x^*_3} \frac{\partial x^*_3}{\partial t}\Delta t\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```